# How do I read lines from a file in a loop?

Tags: bash, loops

my goal is to TTS each line of a text file

First I count the number of lines of my text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(cat /home/mytext.txt | wc -l)
```

I want to define a loop:

```
let "n = $LINES"
while [ $n -ne 0 ]

TTS "the first line"
sleep 5

let "n--"
done
exit
```

Then the loop repeats to read the next line ...etc, as long as the next line exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to `read`:

```
cat /home/mytext.txt |\
while IFS='' read -r CUR_LINE || [ -n "$CUR_LINE" ]; do
   do_something_with "$CUR_LINE"
done
```

It will: cat your text file, read the next line until no more lines are left and do something with each line. Note, the `|| [ -n "$CUR_LINE" ]` bit is to ensure that if the text file doesn't end with a blank line the `while` doesn't end with an error state (non-zero exit code). That matters if you run your script with `set -e` (to terminate on error).

Comment: Re: "That matters if you run your script with `set -e` (to terminate on error)": Eh? That seems completely irrelevant and unrelated to me. The reason for the `|| [ -n "$CUR_LINE" ]` is so that if the input is missing a trailing newline, then the last line will still get processed.

Comment: ++; however, better to use input redirection (`<`) after the `done` to provide input rather than using a pipeline - and therefore subshells - with `cat`. (You may have deliberately opted to use `\ ` to explicitly showcase the line-continuation character here, but note that it's not necessary after `|` - if the current line isn't a complete command, Bash will continue parsing on the following line(s)).

Comment: @ruakh: Good point about the reason. `set -e` is indeed _irrelevant_ here, but it is not _unrelated_: "The `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, or `elif` reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word, or any command of an AND-OR list other than the last."  - from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25_03). In other words: `set -e` explicitly doesn't apply to commands executed in _conditionals_ (among other exceptions).

Comment: Yes, the text file is just a list of "things to buy". For the TTS to speech correctly, i need to "sed" some special characters in utf8 code. For exemple, sed 's/é/%C3%A9/g'. What do i have to write in the "do_something_with" ? TTS "$CUR_LINE" | sed 's/é/%C3%A9/g' for example ?

Comment: @mklement0: The behavior you cite is exactly *why* I consider it unrelated. But, OK; I suppose no two things in the Universe are really *completely* unrelated.

Comment: @pyrrhus: That is a separate question. To ask it, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

Comment: @ruakh: My point was: you are correct that `set -e` doesn't _apply_ here, but it _relates_ to it in that a nonzero exit code in a `while` conditional is a stated _exception_, and one can see how someone could (mistakenly) _think_ it applies.

Comment: @ruakh: Let me try a more pragmatic summary: Explaining _why_ it doesn't apply is more helpful than saying that it's _completely unrelated_ - hence my comments.

Comment: @mklement0: But even if `set -e` *did* apply, the statement in the answer would not make sense, since adding `|| [ -n "$CUR_LINE" ]` does not prevent the condition from becoming false -- it just potentially delays it by one iteration. The purpose of comments on Stack Overflow is supposedly to help improve questions and comments; I don't always hew to that, but in this case the only improvement is to remove the bogus statement, not to write a long explanation of the various ways that it's bogus.

Comment: @ruakh: To be clear: your comment about the true purpose of `|| [ -n "$CUR_LINE" ]` is correct, and kudos for making it.
We are well into meta-commentary at this point, but to reiterate my point: saying "this is completely unrelated" is less helpful than saying "this doesn't apply, because ..." (cont'd in next comment).

Comment: (con't from previous comment) As for the technicalities: You are also correct that the `|| …` clause would _eventually_ indicate failure (nonzero exit code), at which point, if `set -e` _did_ apply, the script would still abort - but, as stated, it doesn't, because `set -e` doesn't apply to conditionals used in a `while` loop. It boils down to this: there are many subtleties, and it's easy to see how someone could _think_ that `set -e` applies. To dissuade them of that notion,
it's better to either explain the issue (space permitting) or link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @ruakh: P.S: Absolutely agreed re removing the incorrect statement from the answer - but my point is that explaining _why_ it should be removed is more likely to achieve that.